# Add url redirect for GET requests only

Tags: asp.net-core, redirect, url-rewriting

I'm configuring my asp.net core app with a redirect rule like this to append a slash at the end:

```
app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions().AddRedirect("(.*[^/])$", "$1/"));
```

But for some reason when doing a POST request without a slash, the request gets converted to a GET-request? I'm not sure why this happens but one work around I was thinking of is to only apply this rewrite rule for GET-requests and ignore the other methods. But how do I configure the rewriter to do this?

Comment: If you want to require a trailing slash, then you should make sure that all your URLs are actually generated that way. Otherwise, with an exclusion to your rule, a POST would still go to a path without a trailing slash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write your own redirect rule like

```
public class RedirectRuleTest : IRule
{
    public void ApplyRule(RewriteContext context)
    {
        HttpRequest request = context.HttpContext.Request;

        if(request.Method == "GET")
        {
            //Add your conditions
            //for example following code adds "/" to any urlwhich is not ending with "/"

            if (!request.Path.Value.ToLower().EndsWith("/"))
            {
                context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect($"{request.Path.Value}/");
                context.Result = RuleResult.SkipRemainingRules;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Startup.cs `Confgure`:

```
app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions().Add(new RedirectRuleTest()));
app.UseRouting();
```